# Granting service control manager access permission to user outside of administrator group

Tags: windows, security, permissions, service, user-permissions

I have a user outside of administrator group.
How can I grant service control manager access permission for that (specific) user?

It's like SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS from the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: You might have to write a program (using the OpenSCManager and SetServiceObjectSecurity functions).  Keep in mind that if you do this the user will be able to give himself administrator access if he or she wants to.

Comment: Users of administrator group are able to do that. Which exactly of the settings of the administrator group triggers that?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279392/on-non-admin-account-openscmanager-function-returns-null may be it can help

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky: the service control manager has an ACL which, by default, explicitly grants full access to the Administrators group.

Comment: Bwah, I didn't know there can be such a thing.. By the way, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/03/13/troubleshooting-msdtc-permission-issues-when-a-distributed-transaction-starts.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try the `sc.exe` with sdset command. It uses sddl format and I'm not sure if you can implement your needs exactly as you want. See the article [Understanding the SDDL permissions in the ACE_String](http://networkadminkb.com/KB/a6/understanding-the-sddl-permissions-in-the-ace-string.aspx) to convert to sddl format.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Specifically, use `sc sdset SCMANAGER` as described here (but with a different SDDL string, of course): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907460

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of the existing permissions:

```
sc sdshow scmanager

D:(A;;CC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)
```

Replace the SID with the AD group or AD user's SID

```
sc sdset scmanager D:(A;;0xF003F;;;S-1-5-21-3674034044-3586052758-1582440453-1121)(A;;CC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCRPRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCRPWPRC;;;SY)(A;;KA;;;BA)S:(AU;FA;KA;;;WD)(AU;OIIOFA;GA;;;WD)
```