# SC SDSET as Domain User

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-10

I have a dummy service (self created) with the following SDDL on a Windows 10 computer in a domain:

```
sc sdshow ****
```

**Result:**

> D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRC**WDWO;;;AU**)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)

Now if I try with a normal domain account (no local admin rights) to set the permissions with **sc sdset**, I got following error:

```
[SC] OpenSCManager Error 5:

Access denied
```

Can someone help me please? I thought I'm able to set the rights with a domain user because of the second entry where the authenticated user got the same rights as the BuiltIn\Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the permissions on any service also requires the caller to have administrator access to the `Service Control Manager` itself. See:
[Granting service control manager access permission to user outside of administrator group](https://serverfault.com/questions/441015/granting-service-control-manager-access-permission-to-user-outside-of-administra)